# How to export the Google App Engine logs logged via System.out.println()?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I have a Spring application deployed on Google App Engine, and I've put logs via `System.out.println()`.
How do I download the file which contains these logs?
The command,
`appcfg request_logs path_to_war_file path_of_log_file` 
only gives requests and their respective responses.

P.S. I've set log `.level = INFO`

Answer (score 0):

The Google App Engine does not seem to provide a way to download the log files.
For my own application, I created one controller that serves the purpose of sending the logs. Adjust the limit according to your application's needs.

```
   package edu.pratiksanglikar.cmpe281.controllers;

    import org.joda.time.DateTime;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    import com.google.appengine.api.log.AppLogLine;
    import com.google.appengine.api.log.LogQuery;
    import com.google.appengine.api.log.LogServiceFactory;
    import com.google.appengine.api.log.RequestLogs;


    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logs")
    public class LogController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getLogs() {

        String allLogs = "";
        // We use this to break out of our iteration loop, limiting record
        // display to 5 request logs at a time.
        int limit = 10000;

        // This retrieves the offset from the Next link upon user click.
        //String offset = req.getParameter("offset");

        // We want the App logs for each request log
        LogQuery query = LogQuery.Builder.withDefaults();
        query.includeAppLogs(true);

        // Set the offset value retrieved from the Next link click.
        /*if (offset != null) {
          query.offset(offset);
        }*/

        // This gets filled from the last request log in the iteration
        int count = 0;

        // Display a few properties of each request log.
        for (RequestLogs record : LogServiceFactory.getLogService().fetch(query)) {
            String log = "\n";
          log += "REQUEST LOG\n";
          DateTime reqTime = new DateTime(record.getStartTimeUsec() / 1000);
          log += "IP: " + record.getIp() + "\n";
          log += "Method: " + record.getMethod() + "\n";
          log += "Resource " + record.getResource() + "\n";
          log += String.format("\nDate: %s", reqTime.toString());

          allLogs += log;
          // Display all the app logs for each request log.
          for (AppLogLine appLog : record.getAppLogLines()) {
              String appLogLine = "\n";
            appLogLine += "\t" + "APPLICATION LOG" + "\n";
            DateTime appTime = new DateTime(appLog.getTimeUsec() / 1000);
            appLogLine += String.format("\n\tDate: %s", appTime.toString());
            appLogLine += "\n\tLevel: " + appLog.getLogLevel() + "";
            appLogLine += "\n\tMessage: " + appLog.getLogMessage() + "\n";
            allLogs += appLogLine;
          }

          if (++count >= limit) {
            break;
          }
        } 

        // When the user clicks this link, the offset is processed in the
        // GET handler and used to cycle through to the next 5 request logs.
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(allLogs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    }
```